# Can't load the textbox inside the constructor

Tags: c#

I have a form called `SelectCatagoryId` which contains a `DataGridView`. I want to pass the selected `cellvalue`  from here to another form called `Add_product`.

This is the code inside the button event in `SelectcatagoryId`.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    String dgv;
    dgv = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    Add_product ap = new Add_product(dgv);
    this.Close();
}
```

This is the code inside `Add_product` form

```
namespace Supermarket
{
    public partial class Add_product : Form
    {

        public Add_product()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection con;
        string file;

        public Add_product(String datagridvalue)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(datagridvalue);
            textBox10.Text = Convert.ToString(datagridvalue);
        }
```

`MessageBox` is working correctly,value of dgv in form `selectCatagoryId` is passed correctly to form `Add_product`, but I can't assign the value of variable `datagridvalue` to `textBox10.Text`.

Comment: why do you convert string to string? try textBox10.Text = datagridvalue;

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Please format your source code samples properly in future posts. A ragged left indentation of statements that should be on the same indentation level can be extremely confusing.

Comment: he is missing the `InitializeComponent();` in overload of the constructor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before assign text to textBox you need to show form Add_product.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    String dgv;
    dgv = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    Add_product ap = new Add_product();
    ap.Show();
    ap.SetProduct(dgv);
    this.Close();
}
```

...

Also add this method to  Add_product class

```
    public SetProduct(String datagridvalue)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(datagridvalue);
        textBox10.Text = datagridvalue;
    }
```

Comment: thanx for de answer. bt nw here displaying an another Add_product form. previous form doesn't work as before. pls help.. :(

Comment: So instead of create new form: Add_product ap = new Add_product(); you need to access to opened form. It can be found in Application.OpenForms collection). And after that you need to call SetProduct method

Comment: yes im trying on this. bt how should i close the opened Add_Product form.
 Add_product ap = new Add_product(); ap.Close(); ap.Hide(); ap.Dispose() methods are not working. pls help

Comment: @KasunMadhupaUdawaththa - You need to iterate over all opene forms to find Add_product form: like this FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form frm in fc)
{ // If is App_product - setProduct, close or whatever you want
}// If you App_product not in opened form - you need to create it, show it and after that sett text to text box

Answer (score 1):

Even with you are creating a `overload of constructor`, you need to `InitializeComponent()` so all the instance of the controls are created.

```
public Add_product(String datagridvalue)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // MessageBox.Show(datagridvalue);
    textBox10.Text = Convert.ToString(datagridvalue);

}
```

By default all the `UI Component` are initiated within the constructor of the form.
And `Visual Studio` generates all the Initialization in the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Comment: my Add_product form is loading by an another button event. therefore i cant follow that method. please give me a solution....

Comment: @KasunMadhupaUdawaththa - look at my code, u have call `InitializeComponent();` before calling `textBox10.Text = Convert.ToString(datagridvalue);`

Comment: @KasunMadhupaUdawaththa - you dont need to change how you are showing the form.